# Error with Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I'm pretty new to `Elasticsearch` and i'm running into this error.

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::ServiceUnavailable at /search

[503] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]","status":503}
```

This is the complete error log

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::ServiceUnavailable - [503] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]","status":503}:
  elasticsearch-transport (1.0.5) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:132:in `__raise_transport_error'
  elasticsearch-transport (1.0.5) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:224:in `perform_request'
  elasticsearch-transport (1.0.5) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
  elasticsearch-transport (1.0.5) lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:104:in `perform_request'
  elasticsearch-api (1.0.5) lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/search.rb:158:in `search'
  elasticsearch-model (0.1.6) lib/elasticsearch/model/searching.rb:51:in `execute!'
  elasticsearch-model (0.1.6) lib/elasticsearch/model/response.rb:31:in `response'
  elasticsearch-model (0.1.6) lib/elasticsearch/model/response/records.rb:34:in `ids'
  elasticsearch-model (0.1.6) lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:16:in `records'
  elasticsearch-model (0.1.6) lib/elasticsearch/model/response/records.rb:64:in `respond_to?'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:17:in `blank?'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:24:in `present?'
   () home/pavan/Roorah/app/controllers/visitors_controller.rb:34:in `search'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:50:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:26:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.3) lib/quiet_assets.rb:23:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.5.251) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
   () home/pavan/Roorah/bin/rails:8:in `require'
   () home/pavan/Roorah/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
  spring (1.1.3) bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
   () home/pavan/Roorah/bin/spring:16:in `require'
   () home/pavan/Roorah/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
   () rails:3:in `load'
   () rails:3:in `<main>'
```

This is the piece of code from `visitors_controller.rb` believed to be the reason behind the error.

```
@search_results = Property.where(property_active: true)

 ### new search
 results   = CityCoordinate.search(params[:q]).records
 if params[:q].present? && results.present? #line 34
 latitude  = results.first.latitude
 longitude = results.first.longitude
 city      = Property.new("latitude" => latitude, "longitude" => longitude)
 @search_results = city.nearbys(200).where(property_active: true)
 end
 ###
```

These are request parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"Holtsville, NY, United States", "min"=>"", "max"=>"", "baths"=>"", "beds"=>"", "property_type"=>"", "pet"=>"", "garage"=>"", "controller"=>"visitors", "action"=>"search"}
```

**Update:**

Below is the log of things which are executed while search

```
Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Holtsville%2C+NY%2C+United+States&min=&max=&baths=&beds=&property_type=&pet=&garage=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-16 09:53:30 +0530
Processing by VisitorsController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"Holtsville, NY, United States", "min"=>"", "max"=>"", "baths"=>"", "beds"=>"", "property_type"=>"", "pet"=>"", "garage"=>""}
  CityCoordinate Load (283.1ms)  SELECT  "city_coordinates".* FROM "city_coordinates"   ORDER BY "city_coordinates"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
2015-03-16 09:54:30 +0530: POST http://localhost:9200/city_coordinates/city_coordinate/_bulk?type=city_coordinate [status:200, request:60.010s, query:60.005s]
2015-03-16 09:54:30 +0530: > {"index":{"_id":1}}
{"id":1,"latitude":40.81,"longitude":-73.04,"zipcode":544,"city":"Holtsville","state":"NY","created_at":"2015-03-10T06:21:50.061Z","updated_at":"2015-03-10T06:21:50.061Z"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"id":2,"latitude":18.16,"longitude":-66.72,"zipcode":601,"city":"Adjuntas","state":"PR","created_at":"2015-03-10T06:21:50.120Z","updated_at":"2015-03-10T06:21:50.120Z"}

2015-03-16 09:54:30 +0530: < {"took":60005,"errors":true,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"city_coordinates","_type":"city_coordinate","_id":"1","status":503,"error":"UnavailableShardsException[[city_coordinates][2] Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned is a known node. Timeout: [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@5f0340e0]"}},{"index":{"_index":"city_coordinates","_type":"city_coordinate","_id":"2","status":503,"error":"UnavailableShardsException[[city_coordinates][3] Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned is a known node. Timeout: [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@2d813d7b]"}}]}
2015-03-16 09:54:30 +0530: GET http://localhost:9200/city_coordinates/city_coordinate/_search?q=Holtsville%2C+NY%2C+United+States [status:503, request:0.028s, query:N/A]
2015-03-16 09:54:30 +0530: < {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]","status":503}
2015-03-16 09:54:30 +0530: [503] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]","status":503}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60402ms
```

Log from `elasticsearch`

```
pavan@Pavan-Inspiron-3542:~/elasticsearch-1.4.4/bin$ ./elasticsearch
[2015-03-16 09:49:18,455][INFO ][node                     ] [Ant-Man] version[1.4.4], pid[2980], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
[2015-03-16 09:49:18,499][INFO ][node                     ] [Ant-Man] initializing ...
[2015-03-16 09:49:18,518][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Ant-Man] loaded [], sites []
[2015-03-16 09:49:22,526][INFO ][node                     ] [Ant-Man] initialized
[2015-03-16 09:49:22,527][INFO ][node                     ] [Ant-Man] starting ...
[2015-03-16 09:49:22,711][INFO ][transport                ] [Ant-Man] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.1.20:9300]}
[2015-03-16 09:49:22,740][INFO ][discovery                ] [Ant-Man] elasticsearch/lZbmLwgxTdC9zwU0qcYrUw
[2015-03-16 09:49:26,516][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Ant-Man] new_master [Ant-Man][lZbmLwgxTdC9zwU0qcYrUw][Pavan-Inspiron-3542][inet[/10.0.1.20:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-03-16 09:49:26,532][INFO ][http                     ] [Ant-Man] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.1.20:9200]}
[2015-03-16 09:49:26,532][INFO ][node                     ] [Ant-Man] started
[2015-03-16 09:49:27,317][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Ant-Man] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
[2015-03-16 09:54:30,813][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Ant-Man] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]
[2015-03-16 09:54:30,815][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Ant-Man] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]
[2015-03-16 09:54:30,847][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Ant-Man] All shards failed for phase: [query]
```

And i have these in the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model', '0.1.6'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', '0.1.6'
gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails', '0.0.4'
```

I can't figure what is happening and i'm stuck with this.In our rails app we use `elasticsearch` for the `renters` to search for the `properties` posted by the `landlords` with the `city,state and country` being the parameters of **`q`**. Currently there is a property with the given city **Holtsville**.

Please do ask if any information is required.

**Update 1:**

The output when i run  `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v&pretty'`

```
pavan@Pavan-Inspiron-3542:~/elasticsearch-1.4.4/bin$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v&pretty'

index            shard prirep state      docs store ip        node        
city_coordinates 2     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 2     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 0     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 0     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 3     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 3     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 1     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 1     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 4     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
city_coordinates 4     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
properties       4     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
properties       4     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
properties       0     p      STARTED       0  115b 127.0.1.1 Franz Kafka 
properties       0     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
properties       3     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
properties       3     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
properties       1     p      STARTED       0  115b 127.0.1.1 Franz Kafka 
properties       1     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
properties       2     p      STARTED       1 7.3kb 127.0.1.1 Franz Kafka 
properties       2     r      UNASSIGNED
```

**Update 2:**

I uncommented and added these things in `elasticsearch.yml` file

```
node.name: "Franz Kafka"
node.master: true
node.data: true
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: true
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low: 97
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high: 99
bootstrap.mlockall: true
network.bind_host: localhost
script.disable_dynamic: true
network.publish_host: localhost
```

And i created an executable  file called `elasticsearch` in `/etc/init.d` to add these `environment variables`

```
ES_MIN_MEM=256m
ES_MAX_MEM=1g
```

**Update 3:**

The output when i run `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty`

```
pavan@Pavan-Inspiron-3542:~/elasticsearch-1.4.4/bin$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 3,
  "active_shards" : 3,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 17
}
```

**Update 4:**

According to this [**link**](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html),it seems like my machine didn't have the minimum **8GB of RAM(I have 4GB)**. Is this the reason for the error? And also the `city_coordinates` table(which the `elasticsearch` collects the data from) has **43k** records which gives me enough reason to believe that the current memory(**4GB**) is not sufficient for `elasticsearch`.

**Update 5:**

The output when i run `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'`

```
pavan@Pavan-Inspiron-3542:~/elasticsearch-1.4.4/bin$ curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'
host                ip        heap.percent ram.percent load node.role master name        
Pavan-Inspiron-3542 127.0.1.1            6          41 0.49 d         *      Franz Kafka
```

Comment: Run this command `GET /_cat/shards?v&pretty` and provide the output in a gist.

Comment: What did you do to the cluster before you saw this? Moving nodes, removing nodes from the cluster, adding nodes? Also, I doubt the logs show only that. Can you post somewhere the `[NODE_NAME].log` file? (complete one)

Comment: @AndreiStefan I'm pretty new to elasticsearch and unfortunately don't know nothing about clusters,nodes and that stuff you are talking about. I just started the elasticsearch server and in another terminal i executed the command you requested.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I added the latest changes that i made before executing `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v&pretty'`

Comment: Do you need the data you have now in Elasticsearch? Or you are ok with deleting what's in it now and starting over?

Comment: Something that may be useful would be to install the Head plugin (https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) and then you can go to `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head` for a visual representation of your cluster's state, and hopefully more information.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I don't mind deleting the data and starting over again,i just working in a localhost.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Please find my update regarding hardware required for `elasticsearch`

Comment: @Chris Heald Please find my update regarding hardware required for `elasticsearch`

Comment: 4GB is plenty; it shouldn't cause you to experience this issue. Your problem is that your machine can't allocate shards to the node. See the updates to my answer.

Comment: @Pavan my suggestion at this point is to start over the entire process. Delete your ES instance, start with a fresh one out of the box, *make sure only one node is in your cluster*, index your documents, test.

Comment: @Pavan First make your cluster health to green then proceed to the search hits, and if possible can you please update your questions with the index settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is logged here:

> Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned is a known node.

This usually means that Elasticsearch is unable to create the primary shard for your index. Often, this is because your disk is too full:

> cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low controls the low watermark for disk usage. It defaults to 85%, meaning ES will not allocate new shards to nodes once they have more than 85% disk used.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html

You should probably set your Elasticsearch log level to DEBUG for more information.

Edit: Based on your shard debug output, it looks like you've created your index with 20 shards, but your nodes won't accomodate that many.

> The index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node setting allows to control how many total shards (replicas and primaries) for an index will be allocated per node.

You should recreate your index with `number_of_replicas` and `number_of_shards` set to values such that `number_of_shards * number_of_replicas` is less than `index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node`, and `number_of_replicas` is no larger than the number of nodes in your cluster.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: I was little late to understand this line **You should recreate your index** Now i deleted the indexes and recreated them.It is working great now.Thanks.